# GWT Generates the wrong classes in the wrong files (ClassNotFoundException)

Tags: gwt, generator, classnotfoundexception

I am using generators to generate quite a lot of utility classes in my GWT client-side application.

For some reason, on rebind, I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundExceotion`, which states it cannot find a particular class:

```
Could not load deferred binding result type 'fr.orange.livebox.gui.businessmodelfactory.json.networks.wan.DataBinder_RoadWarriorVPN_Impl'
```

When I look at my generated classes, in `generated/fr/orange/livebox/gui/buisinessmodelfactory/json/networks/wan/`, I see that the file exists, **BUT** it contains the declaration for a completely different class, which was rebound before it (the previous class was rebound at the home page, whereas this one was rebound on a different page).

I just don't understand why GWT should be putting class files with the wrong classes in. I have tried deleting the generated files, but each time it does it again.

Incidentally, the class which is found in the wrong file, has already been correctly generated in its own file, I can just see it in both, which is simply bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that a generator is instantiated once, and the generate method is called again on the same instance each time, thus any properties are effectively cached. I was using a cached `ClassSourceFileComposerFactory` instance with a method called `getComposer()` which would check if `null`, if it is, instantiate, otherwise `return`. This was leaving a cached `ClassSourceFileComposerFactory` which would always have the same class in mind.